# Bash - make counter print superscript numbers

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, tr

If I had a script with a counter, printing numbers like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
  i=$((i+1))
  echo "$i"
done;
```

prints:

```
1
2
3
4
5
[...]
```

**how can I make the script print superscript numbers?**

so I would get:

```
¹
²
³
⁴
⁵
[...]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` (at least the implementation on my machine) doesn't seem to handle UTF-8 characters correctly. GNU sed can do that, and its `y` operator works the same way as `tr`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
while : ; do
((++i))
sed 'y/0123456789/⁰¹²³⁴⁵⁶⁷⁸⁹/' <<< "$i"
done
```

Don't forget to save the script as UTF-8 and configure the terminal to display UTF-8 correctly.

Comment: is `:` just a shortcut for `true` in a bash `while` loop?

Comment: @nath: Yes, see `help :`.